# Split a string vector with ' [ ] ' in R

Tags: string, r, vector, split

I have a string something like that:

```
nw.str <- "[D][A|D][T|A:D][C|T]"
```

And I need to split it in this way:

```
"[D]" "[A|D]" "[T|A:D]" "[C|T]"
```

Comment: It is considered bad form to cross-post to R-help and SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in `base` R just using `strsplit` and zero-width assertions (they match characters but don't *use them up*). Basically we look for close braces followed by open braces and open braces preceeded by close braces and split between them....

```
strsplit( x , "(?<=\\])(?=\\[)"  , perl = TRUE )
#[[1]]
#[1] "[D]"     "[A|D]"   "[T|A:D]" "[C|T]"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I use `stringr::str_replace_all` to insert a space between the values.  Then just split that string at the space.

```
> library(stringr)
> s <- str_replace_all(nw.str, fixed("]["), fixed("] ["))
> strsplit(s, " ")[[1]]  ## or unlist(strsplit(...))
# [1] "[D]"     "[A|D]"   "[T|A:D]" "[C|T]"
```

Another way that uses base R (there are many),

```
> g <- gsub("][", "] [", nw.str, fixed = TRUE)
> unlist(strsplit(g, " "))
```

Answer (score 3):

With `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) we specify what we want to extract (rather than what we want to split at).

In this case we want to extract a left square bracket `"\\["` followed by anything `".*?"` (but the shortest anything rather than the longest as indicaed by the question mark) followed by a right square brakcet `"\\]"`.

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(nw.str, "\\[.*?\\]")[[1]]
```

giving:

```
[1] "[D]"     "[A|D]"   "[T|A:D]" "[C|T]"
```

Comment: `gsubfn` looks like a really useful package.  Thanks for introducing me.

Answer (score 1):

A qdap approach:

```
library(qdap)
bracketXtract(nw.str, with=TRUE)

##      all1      all2      all3      all4 
##     "[D]"   "[A|D]" "[T|A:D]"   "[C|T]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `strsplit`:

```
splitted <- strsplit(nw.str,"][", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
splitted[[1]] <- paste(splitted[[1]], "]", sep="")
splitted[2:length(splitted)-1] <- paste("[", splitted[2:length(splitted)-1], "]", sep="")
splitted[[length(splitted)]] <- paste("[", splitted[[length(splitted)]], sep="")
splitted
```